# Puzzling angular-cli AOT error

Tags: angular-cli, angular2-aot

I am using angular-cli. I build the app with

```
ng b --aot
```

only to see the following type of error:

> ERROR in /home/tora/repos/my-repo/console/src/$$_gendir/app/pods/unit-results/unit-results.component.ngfactory.ts (114,35): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

I'm at a loss how to track down this error. The app lints, compiles, and runs in non-AOT mode with no issues. When the build command terminates, any `$$_gendir` directory is long gone so there's nothing for me to look at.

Comment: Please post the code for the `unit-results.component` and template.  AOT is much stricter when enforcing compilation rules so many times you won't see error until you run AOT.

Comment: please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to have been two problems:

1. a `@HostListener` decorator on a method.
2. a missing parameter to `ngOnChanges`, which TS was perfectly happy about.

Comment: How did you track this down?